# Sorting of dictionary in a list by value in unicode format in dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, unicode

I have a dictionary having values in fiven format.

```
{
    'name': l.employee_id.name,
    'acc_no': l.name,
    'ifsc_code': l.ifsc_code,
    'bysal': l.bysal,
    'debit_credit': l.debit_credit,
}
```

and it append to a list 'result'.

Now result has value =

```
[{'ifsc_code': u'234', 'bysal': 4985.0, 'debit_credit': u'C', 'name': u'Ammu Kripalal', 'acc_no': u'789789'}, {'ifsc_code': u'546546456121', 'bysal': 7470.0, 'debit_credit': u'C', 'name': u'Ajayakumar KN', 'acc_no': u'SBI0814278'}, {'ifsc_code': u'54666555', 'bysal': 7571.25, 'debit_credit': u'C', 'name': u'Ramesh', 'acc_no': u'6657567'}, {'ifsc_code': u'5466655554656', 'bysal': 19220.0, 'debit_credit': u'C', 'name': u'Vineesh V', 'acc_no': u'23465778'}, {'ifsc_code': u'985654', 'bysal': 7080.0, 'debit_credit': u'C', 'name': u'Abith Ganesh', 'acc_no': u'676'}, {'ifsc_code': u'SIBL0000488', 'bysal': 9680.0, 'debit_credit': u'C', 'name': u'Ammu G', 'acc_no': u'123'}]
```

I want to sort dictionary based on ifsc_code.
I tried with

```
sorted(result, key=itemgetter('ifsc_code'))
```

but it is not working.

Since it is a unicode string, While sorting it consider only the first letter of ifsc_code.

How can I solve this issue.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is working, but since they're strings, they get sorted in alphabetical order. not by the numerical value.

Comment: One of your `ifsc_code`s is `SIBL0000488`. How do you want that to be treated?

Comment: @M4rtini , Thanks. I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

Use an integer comparison instead of a string comparison:

```
def get_ifsc(record):
    return int(record.ifsc_code)

print sorted(result, key=get_ifsc)
```

The code `SIBL0000488` is problematic and it is unclear how you would want it sorted.  Once possibility it to strp the letters and keep only the numeric portion of the key:

```
def get_ifsc(record):
    return int(''.join(filter(unicode.isdigit, record.ifsc_code)))
```

Comment: `int()` does not accept all `isdigit()` characters e.g., `u'\u00b2'`; `isdecimal()` could be used instead.